# Items appear to float mid-air

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been playing Skyrim (Well, its my 4th year with it), and have noticed many times that some of the items in particular rooms are floating in mid-air.

Like, when I enter The Palace of the Kings, everything on the table in front of Ulfric's throne is floating well above the table. Like, I need to jump to get to the stuff. Is there any known fix?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of one of these situations? Does this happen on every game or just a specific save? Have you tried disabling some/all mods to see if that fixes it?

Comment: On what platform are you playing? And if you are playing on PC, do you use mods?

Comment: I am indeed on PC, and the issue is perennial, that is, it is not mod specific. It has been happening even to non modded areas as described above.

Comment: It is a problem with specific vanilla areas, that occurred even before I installed mods. Also, it is more prominent in areas such as black reach.

Comment: I've seen it regularly on PC and haven't installed any mods yet. Supposedly,  the unofficial patches fix many of these... but since I haven't tried it yet, I can't suggest that as an official answer. Perhaps someone who's used those mods can report.

Comment: @JohnLaviolette The issue persists. I am using them.

Comment: Yesterday I found a single green apple floating 10m in the air above a nordic ruin near Shor's Stone... Got me thinking about life and that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no answer. This is a well-known glitch and happens all over Skyrim. (Sorry!)

If you're comfortable with the console, you could manually bring them down, but it's probably not worth your time.

My advice is to roll your eyes and resolve that if you ever work on any software, you will debug it better than those who have gone before you...because you won't fix this bug.

Comment: I think this is accurate, I've seen this issue in Skyrim and Oblivion. Basically you enter a room and as all the physics load, the items on tables shift ever so slightly and end up floating above whatever they were supposed to be laying on. However the issue OP describes states he has to jump to get to the items, my own experience has only shown me items a few inches off the laying surfaces.

Comment: Same, though it's been as high as head-level for me on rare occasions. I suspect it's the same glitch, but perhaps not?